# Is there a way to get the calling information inside the body of a function defined using down value?

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

Suppose a function has multiple argument structure like follows:

```
f[a_,{b_,c___}]:=... Echo[{ArgumentSequence[]},"called with:"] ...;
f[{a_,b_},c___]:=... Echo[{ArgumentSequence[]},"called with:"] ...;
f[{{a_},b_},c___]:=... Echo[{ArgumentSequence[]},"called with:"] ...;
...
```

Is there a function `ArgumentSequence` that would get the sequence of arguments by which the function was called instead of hardwiring it in every definition?

So for `f[{10,11},12,13]`, `ArgumentSequence[]` when called inside the body would evaluate to `Sequence[{10,11},12,13]`. Note if the function `f` had `Hold` attribute on an argument like `HoldFirst` then for `f[{10,a},b,13]` where `a=11 and b=12`, `ArgumentSequence[]` gives `Sequence[HoldForm[{10,a}],12,13]`.

Basically this is just like the `SlotSequence` for pure functions, `...Echo[{#0,##},"calling information:"]...&[...]`.

Also `#0` evaluate to the full definition of the pure function since it doesn't have a name but for the case of functions defined using `DownValues` is there a similar analog which instead of returning the `DownValue` information returns the name of the function `f`.

Also is there a function `DownValueMatch` which when called gives the rule which will be matched.

So for example, if I call `DownValueMatch[f[{10,11},12,13]]` will give

```
{HoldPattern[f[{a_, b_}, c___]] :>  ... Echo[ArgumentSequence[],"called with:"] ...}
```

Comment: maybe `foo[p : PatternSequence[{a_, b_}, c_]] := (Echo[{p}];...)`?

Comment: Why not just have a wrapper function `g[args__] := Module[(* stuff *), Echo[{args}, "called with:"]; f[args]]`, and leave the special cases to `f`'s definitions?